# How to convert a Twitter Future[Map[A, Future[C]]] to a Future[Map[A, C]]

Tags: scala, twitter, dictionary, future, finagle

I am trying to fix the following issue:

I have a Future[Map[A, B]]. For all B, I need to apply a method that convert B to a Future[C] and I want to give back a Future[Map[A, C]]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def getClients(clientIds: Seq[Int]): Future[Map[Int, ClientData]] = {

  def getClientData(clientInfo: ClientInfo): Future[ClientData] = 
    clientInfo match {
      case ValidInfo(info) => getData(info)
      case _ => throw new Exception
    }

  client.getClients(clientIds) map {
    _.toMap map {
      case (clientId: Int, clientInfo: ClientInfo) =>
        getClientData(clientInfo) map {
          clientData => (clientId, clientData)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**This code is wrong as it returns a Iterable[Future[(Int, ClientData)]]**

For info *getClients* is a thrift method that returns *Future[Map[A, B]]* where the Map is mutable, so I need to convert it to an immutable map first with toMap.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
scala> def f: Future[Map[String, Future[Int]]] = ???
f: Future[Map[String,Future[Int]]]

scala> def x = for {
     |   m <- f
     |   i = m.map{ case (k, fv) => fv.map{ k -> _ } }
     |   l <- Future.sequence(i)
     | } yield l.toMap
x: Future[Map[String,Int]]
```

Step by step:

Convert `Future[Map[A, Future[B]]]` to `Future[Iterable[Future[(A, B)]]]`:

```
scala> def x1 = f.map{ _.map{ case (k, fv) => fv.map{ k -> _ } } }
x1: Future[Iterable[Future[(String, Int)]]]
```

Convert `Iterable[Future[(A, B)]]` to `Future[Iterable[(A, B)]]` and `flatten` `Future[Future[...]]` using `flatMap`:

```
scala> def x2 = x1.flatMap{ Future.sequence(_) }
x2: Future[immutable.Iterable[(String, Int)]]
```

Convert `Iterable[(A, B)]` to `Map[A, B]`:

```
scala> def x = x2.map{ _.toMap }
x: Future[Map[String,Int]]
```

For `com.twitter.util.Future` you should use `collect` instead of `sequence` and `toSeq` before `collect` since it accepts `Seq`:

```
def x = for {
  m <- f
  i = m.map{ case (k, fv) => fv.map{ k -> _ } }
  l <- Future.collect(i.toSeq)
} yield l.toMap
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response!
But there is no Future.sequence in Finagle! There is a Future.collect but it does not seems to work here ...

Comment: @user3063038: what is your scala version? [Here is `sequence` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L487) in 2.10.3.

Comment: I am using 2.10.3 but a com.twitter.util.Future which apparently has no sequence method : http://twitter.github.io/util/util-core/target/doc/main/api/com/twitter/util/Future.html

Comment: @user3063038: see update. `collect` should works just fine (after `toSeq`).

Comment: Yes! I tried it in the meantime as well and it worked! Thanks a lot!